# Fetch new tags for current commit, without fetching newer commits

Tags: git, git-commit, git-pull, git-tag, git-fetch

Let's say I make a commit and push it, then someone else pulls my commit, creates one or more tags on it, makes a few more commits and then pushes everything again.

How can I now fetch the new tags for the commit that I already have on my machine without fetching more commits (i.e. `git pull` doesn't count)?

**Edit:**
My incentive is to save time and resources. 
Basically whenever I push a new commit to GitLab, a chain of automated jobs is triggered within GitLab. The first one analyzes the commit message (which follows a certain convention) and then decides what kind of version bump would be appropriate, then it checks the version tag for the previous commit and creates a new one for the current commit with the appropriate version bump.
Then the next job is triggered. This job might be responsible for compiling the source code. Then another job is triggered which might be responsible for creating a source code archive.
Every job runs within its own temporary Docker container and all containers include a folder representing the repository at the time of pushing. So the newly created tag which is being created in the first job needs to be fetched at the beginning of job 2 and 3 (these jobs need to know the version number, e.g. to give the source code archive a proper name). It would be a waste of resources to do a full `git fetch` every time. Especially when you make multiple commits within a very short period of time.
It is also possible to manually trigger the chain of jobs of an old commit. In that case you would potentially fetch thousands of commits that you don't need for job 2 and 3.
In reality there are actually more like 15 jobs, but I had to simplify things, otherwise I would have to write a book.

Comment: `git fetch --tags`?

Comment: That would fetch ALL commits though, wouldn't it?

Comment: *"in addition to whatever else would otherwise be fetched"*, yes.

Comment: Well, I said "`without fetching more commits`", so that's specifically what I don't want.

Comment: Could you expand on *why*? Unlike `pull` it won't update your workspace, if that's what you're trying to avoid.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It's complicated. I added some text to my question. I hope this makes it clear. If not, feel free to ask.

Comment: It is very unlikely that this would save appreciable resources; I'd test the incremental size of the repo with those unwanted commits, because I'm willing to bet you've spent more resources worrying about this problem than you could ever save.  In fact, depending on how the pack files are laid out in the repo for Step 1, omitting the commits might actually consume *more* resources since objects might have to be repacked just for the sake of omitting the newest commits.  If you want to save resources, I recommend looking into a build process that doesn't involve fetching across so many repos

Comment: It is already optimized very well. But I cannot cross the boundaries of GitLab CI and certain conventions have to be followed. My environment is way too complicated to explain in full detail. So it's just not possible to give good advice on how to improve it. I'm just looking for an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'll offer a solution, but first please refer to my comment on the original question; in summary, I am *extremely* skeptical that this is a valuable endeavor.

To fetch, you have to be able to name what you want to fetch.  IIRC this is considered a security measure of sorts, in that it prevents fetching a known hash if the actual refs have been force-pushed to remove that commit from history.  So you have to name a tag or a branch, or just take everything reachable (more or less).

If step 1 creates, in addition to any calculated version tags, a single tag with a name known to steps 2 and 3, then you can fetch *that* tag with the `--tags` option and get what you're asking for.

```
source-repo $  git tag v1.3.7
source-repo $  git tag -f current_build
source-repo $  cd path/to/target/repo
target-repo $  git fetch source-repo current_build
From url://of/source/repo
 * tag               current_build        -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new tag]         v1.3.7        -> v1.3.7
 * [new tag]         current_build        -> current_build
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly this is not a solution, but rather a workaround. A workaround that would break on the second commit because you would then have two commits tagged with "current_build".

Comment: Okay, can you please add more detail?

Comment: @Forivin - I've tested this; it works.  If you think it doesn't, test it.  If you want help solving a problem - especially one that, as I've been pretty clear, I don't think is a legitimate problem - then I expect you to put in at least as much effort as me, rather than just coming at me saying "well that won't work".  Sorry, not sorry.

Comment: It doesn't work. Tagging multiple commits with the same tag results in errors. I then assumed that I should only have the tag on the latest commit. But as soon as I run `git fetch --tags source-repo current_build` it fetches all tags and all commits. You can see it if you run `git log --all`. So from what I can tell your solution doesn't work. If you are not willing to provide more detail that's fine. But your answer won't be of any help to me then.

Comment: @Forivin - In fact it does work if you follow the steps I outlined.  Did you perhaps miss the `-f` option in the tag command for `current_build`? Tagging multiple commits with the same tag is impossible; but `tag -f` *moves* the tag if it already exists, and fetching that tag then works exactly as expected.  As to whether my solution is of use to you, I already told you it's not because you're solving a non-problem.  But it *is* the solution to the problem you posed.

Comment: Running `git tag -f current_build` worked fine, the issue was that push would throw errors afterwards. Anyway, the tagging was not the problem in the end. The problem was that `git fetch --tags source-repo current_build` fetched new commits and their tags in addition to the tag(s) that I want. As you can see here, at first I was not able to check out a new commit because I didn't fetch it yet, then I ran `git fetch --tags source-repo current_build` and suddenly the commit was fetched. https://i.snag.gy/AnWgoQ.jpg

Comment: @Forivin - If you are pushing a ref you've moved in what git considers an unexpected way, you have to use `-f`, as in `git push -f --tags origin`.  You keep saying that fetching the specified tag pulls all commits; I cannot reproduce that behavior.  Based on your comments I think you're placing the tag incorrectly because when you run into problems, you're assuming you should do other than what I said (and still claiming somehow it's my procedure that isn't working)

Comment: I don't need/expect further replies. Your answer is not the solution to my problem. https://i.snag.gy/kUOXb6.jpg

Comment: @Forivin - Well, you're factually wrong about whether this solves the stated problem, but enjoy your spite

Comment: @Forivin - (and btw - within the constraints you've set, there is no other workable solution.  There are minor variations - like using a branch instead of a tag if you want to open yourself to more problems, or using a different predictable tag name each time if you like clutter.  But essentially your decision to put your dislike of my solution ahead of its functionality means you can choose between your spite or working software.)

Comment: My constraints are mentioned in the question. If you think there is no workable solution then your "solution" doesn't solve the problem, thanks.

Comment: @Forivin - Yes, your constraints are mentioned in the question. And that's why my solution meets them.  Which is actually exactly what I said; you must've misread where I said that no *other* solution will meet them. Not sure where your problem is.  And... it's not what I "think".  It's a fact: git's remote interaction is very simple, and this is the way to do what you've asked.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer : broken solution, answer preserved only for further investigations.*

```
git fetch --tags <commitID>
```

will limit `fetch` command's range to only this commit.

If you have a doubt, first launch a dry run and see what *would* have been done :

```
git fetch --dry-run --tags <commitID>
```

Comment: By commitID you mean the commit hash, right? When I do this, I get `fatal: '<COMMIT_HASH>' does not appear to be a git repository`

Comment: @Forivin Seems it's a bad assumption on my part :-/ the <refspec> passed cannot be a commit hash but only a tag or branch. Sorry but at the moment I don't know if and how what you want is achievable.

Comment: @Forivin Preserved answer to possibly prevent others from doing the same mistake, but if you prefer me to just delete it, of course I will.